# 0x800a138f - Error while debugging javascript

Tags: javascript, ajax, model-view-controller

keep getting the following error, and stuck for answers.

I'm passing some json error data from the controller to view, but stuck with this error.

Any ideas?

[image: Error]

My code is:

```
   <script type="text/javascript">

    var server = "";
function populateDropdown(dropdownId, requestPath, requestData, valueFunction, textFunction) {
    var dropDown = $("#" + dropdownId);
    dropDown.empty();
    $('#myModel').show();
    $.getJSON(requestPath, requestData, function (data) {
        debugger;
        $.each(data.result, function (index, object) {
            dropDown.append($("<option />").val(valueFunction(object)).text(textFunction(object)));
        });
    });
}
</script>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Are all the parameters valid? (not null)?

Comment: Does data return a result? Try in Chrome, perhaps better error messages

Comment: The error is being thrown down the line from the problem. I find this sort of thing easier to debug in the browser's dev tools. Start by inspecting the payload in the network tab.

Comment: Jameson - Params are valid
Mic - i'll try that now thanks

Comment: Go up the call stack until you get to your code, it'll tell you where in your code the problem is.

Comment: Also, you haven't provided source code for the functions that are passed as `valueFunction` and `textFunction`.

Comment: And log `requestPath`, `requestData` (before the `$.getJSON`), and `data` (within the completion handler).